# Remove a property (getter/setter) from an attribute in subclass

Tags: python, properties

This may have been answered somewhere else, but I was wondering if there was any way to remove an attribute/method decorated with `@property` in a subclass.

Example:

```py
from datetime import datetime

class A():
    def __init__(self, num):
        self._num = num

    @property
    def id(self):
        return self._num * datetime.now().timestamp()

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, id, num):
        super().__init__(num)
        self.id = id
```

The above code does not run if you attempt to create an instance of class `B`. `AttributeError: can't set attribute`

The base class uses a property because it needs to evaluate its ID on the fly, while my sub class is able to know its ID when it is created. The `id` attribute is accessed OFTEN, and I am seeing a significant performance hit because I have to use a property to serve this attribute, instead of just accessing it directly. (From what I have read, properties increase time-to-access by 5x). My application is currently spending around 10% of runtime getting this property.

Is there any way I can short-circuit the property in a sub class?

Comment: Why not just make it a normal method? I'm not sure if the property is the actual culprit here, but the datetime manipulation that is going on, requiring a function call and a method call (and a multiplication)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - the ID method in A() is more of an example of an attribute that does require a computation, versus the id in B which does not. The fact that I used datetime as an example should have no consequence compared to any other computation

Comment: You could try `def id(self): return self._id` in B?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to go through several possibilities here. Some of them do what you literally asked. Some of them don't, but they may be better options anyway.

First, your example base class changes the value of `obj.id` on every access due to the passage of time. That's really bizarre and doesn't seem like a useful concept of "ID". If your real use case has a stable `obj.id` return value, then you can cache it to avoid the expense of recomputation:

```
def __init__(self):
    ...
    self._id = None
@property
def id(self):
    if self._id is not None:
        return self._id
    retval = self._id = expensive_computation()
    return retval
```

This may mitigate the expense of the property. If you need more mitigation, look for places where you access `id` repeatedly, and instead, access it once and save it in a variable. Local variable lookup outperforms attribute access no matter how the attribute is implemented. (Of course, if you actually do have weird time-variant IDs, then this sort of refactoring may not be valid.)

Second, you can't override a `property` with a "regular" attribute, but you *can* create your own version of `property` that can be overridden this way. Your `property` blocks attribute setting, and takes priority over "regular" attributes even if you force an entry into the instance `__dict__`, because `property` has a `__set__` method (even if you don't write a setter). Writing your own descriptor without a `__set__` would allow overriding. You could do it with a generic `LowPriorityProperty`:

```
class LowPriorityProperty(object):
    """
    Like @property, but no __set__ or __delete__, and does not take priority
    over the instance __dict__.
    """
    def __init__(self, fget):
        self.fget = fget
    def __get__(self, instance, owner=None):
        if instance is None:
            return self
        return self.fget(instance)

class Foo(object):
    ...
    @LowPriorityProperty
    def id(self):
        ...

class Bar(Foo):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Bar, self).__init__()
        self.id = whatever
    ...
```

Or with a role-specific descriptor class:

```
class IDDescriptor(object):
    def __get__(self, instance, owner=None):
        if instance is None:
            return self
        # Remember, self is the descriptor. instance is the object you're
        # trying to compute the id attribute of.
        return whatever(instance)

class Foo(object):
    id = IDDescriptor()
    ...

class Bar(Foo):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Bar, self).__init__()
        self.id = whatever
        ...
```

The role-specific descriptor performs better than the generic `LowPriorityProperty`, but both perform worse than `property` due to implementing more logic in Python instead of C.

Finally, you can't override a `property` with a "regular" attribute, but you *can* override it with another descriptor, such as another `property`, or such as the descriptors created for `__slots__`. If you're really, really pressed for performance, `__slots__` is probably more performant than any descriptor you could implement manually, but the interaction between `__slots__` and the property is weird and obscure and you'll probably want to leave a comment explaining what you're doing.

```
class Foo(object):
    @property
    def id(self):
        ...

class Bar(Foo):
    __slots__ = ('id',)
    def __init__(self):
        super(Bar, self).__init__()
        self.id = whatever
    ...
```

Answer (score 3):

add a class C as common ancestor, without id.  inherit A and B from it and implement id there as needed.  Python wont care that id doesn’t exist on C.

refactor non-id code/attributes from A to C.

Suitability depends on whether OP controls class hierarchy and instantiation mechanisms.

#### I also found a workaround to get it working as is:

```
from datetime import datetime

class A():
    def __init__(self, num):
        self._num = num

    @property
    def id(self):
        return self._num * datetime.now().timestamp()

class B(A):

    #this fixes the problem
    id = None

    def __init__(self, id, num):
        super().__init__(num)
        self.id = id

b = B("id", 3)
print(vars(b))
```

This will output:

`{'_num': 3, 'id': 'id'}`

The trick is `id = None` on class B.  Basically, Python's attribute/method lookup mechanism will stop at the **first** class with `id` as an attribute in the MRO.  With `id = None` on class B, the lookup stops there and it never gets as far as that pesky @property on A.

If I comment it back out, as per the OP:

```
    self.id = id
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Comment: Oh, right, we can shadow the property descriptor with a class dict entry that isn't a descriptor at all, and then shadow *that* with the instance dict. I should have remembered that option.